# Added new model and controller - user registration suddenly failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I previously changed devise on my rails app to allow me to sign up via a username instead of email and also not require a email. I successfully created an account with no email. Today I added a Profile model and profiles controller and established a relationship with the profile model and my user model.  Now when I try to sign up I receive this error:

"SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"

I've tried adding this migration:

```
  def change
    change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true
  end
```

I've tried adding:

```
  def email_required?
    false
  end
```

to my profile model even though it's already in my user model. I really have no idea where to go from here. I have to assume it has something to do with either the new model or controller because without them it worked fine.

Comment: Sounds like something is trying to insert a duplicate record. What unique constraints (i.e. indexes with uniqueness) are on the table in question?

Comment: Do you have your `config.authentication_keys` set in your devise config?

Comment: @neuronaut
  validates_presence_of       :password, :on=>:create
  validates_confirmation_of   :password, :on=>:create
  validates_length_of         :password, :within => Devise.password_length, :allow_blank => true

Though my first impression is that it seems to be looking for 'users.email' even though the error itself isn't listing an email column.

Comment: @DustinFisher 

config.authentication_keys = [:username]

Comment: Those are the rails validations which aren't involved (or you'd be getting a very different error message). This error is from SQLite and is telling you that some piece of code is trying to insert a record where one or more fields contains a value already found (i.e. it's not unique). If there's a backtrace with the error it should tell you which piece of code is trying to perform the duplicate insertion.

Comment: @neuronaut Perhaps my user_id foreign key I added to my profile model?

Answer (score 1):

The email column still exists in the table and it has UNIQUE Constraint. Check if you have line like this when you create the table `users`:

`add_index :users, :email, unique: true`

It makes sense that two records with empty email lead to this exception.

By the way, it has nothing to do with what you do later (add profile model etc.).

Comment: Very good point, and I think you're right. I tried commenting out the validation you listed and migrated the db, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @JasonMattingly commenting out the validation may not be enough. better drop the contraint with a migration.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. After trying the suggestions here and still receiving the same error message I ended up removing the entire email column from users via:

```
rails generate migration remove_email_from_users email:string
```

I wrote my own validations otherwise I'm guessing this would cause problems for the :validatable part of devise. If anyone knows of any potentially serious issues from solving the problem this way, please comment here. My own project is small so I don't think it will be an issue, but people googling this thread in the future may find it helpful to know what this might cause in their apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a migration like this:

```
def change
  change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true
  remove_index :users, :email
end
```

Devise adds this when it runs the first time: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")`

That is causing your failure saying null is already present in the table.